# Identify icon overlay in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, winapi, icons

I'm on a quest to figure out how to identify different icon overlays through `Excel VBA`.

There is a cloud syncing software and I am trying to identify whenever the syncing of my excel file has finished or still in progress. I was able to achieve a basic level of reliability by following the modification date of some meta(?) files but there is not enough consistency to fully rely on this method.

The result of my searches is a big punch in the face, since there is not much info about it in `VBA`. Basically all I have found that everyone uses advanced languages like `C++` to handle these things.

The closest source I've got in `VBA` does something similar with the `System Tray` and uses the `shell32.dll` calling the appropiate `windows api` ([link](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?34563-Show-system-tray-balloon-tooltip-in-VBA)). But I have no idea how to make it to the `Shell Icon Overlay Identifier`.

What do you guys think, is there a possible way to make it through `VBA` or I have to learn `C++`?

Comment: Cloud services often have web APIs that allow you to query them for status etc. that seems a better approach than messing around with overlay icons.  `SHGetFileInfo` can be used to return the index of the overlay icon for a given file, you would need to experiment to see what index relates to what and how constant they are between reboots, perhaps using a fixed file with a known synced status.

Comment: Overlay icon is the wrong approach. Doubt it's even tractable. Use the API.

Comment: I've tried to mess around with the API in C++, going through the steps with an example but the built wasnt successful gave me errors. Unfortunatelly I don't have the capacity to get on that level with the language where I can deal with it. Thanks for the `SHGetFileInfo` tip! I will check out what I can do with it.

Comment: Who the hell would downvote a question like this and why? Insane...

Comment: @Bernat: Because, you use wrong approach. What if Explorer is not default shell? Or Explorer crashed at moment, when you try get sync status? David Heffernan points to right solution.

Comment: Using VBA it's a legit approach since it's working and that was the point of the question, to get it work. Maybe it's not the optimal solution. An SQL database with a C++ interface using the cloud SDK would be better. As an extra I could set up my own super secure webserver to deal with the syncronization according to my own needs. Unfortunatelly all of these would take me for a year at least. This VBA solution got me what I was looking for in the question which is exactly what I wanted. You don't try to buy a sport car when you don't even have enough money for the gas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Awesome! It is possible! The** `SHGetFileInfo` **method works!**

It gives me values according to the current overlays. Here is the code for any other crazy people who wanna mess around with it:

```
Const SHGFI_ICON = &H100
Const SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX = &H40
Const MAX_PATH = 260
Const SYNCED = 100664316    'own specific value
Const UNDSYNC = 117442532   'own specific value

Private Type SHFILEINFO
    hIcon As Long                       'icon
    iIcon As Long                       'icon index
    dwAttributes As Long                'SFGAO_ flags
    szDisplayName As String * MAX_PATH  'display name (or path)
    szTypeName As String * 80           'type name
End Type

Private Declare Function SHGetFileInfo Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHGetFileInfoA" _
    (ByVal pszPath As String, _
    ByVal dwFileAttributes As Long, _
    psfi As SHFILEINFO, _
    ByVal cbFileInfo As Long, _
    ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long

Private Sub GetThatInfo()
    Dim FI As SHFILEINFO
    SHGetFileInfo "E:\Test.xlsm", 0, FI, Len(FI), SHGFI_ICON Or SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX
    Select Case FI.iIcon
        Case SYNCED
            Debug.Print "Synchronized"
        Case UNDSYNC
            Debug.Print "Synchronization in progress"
        Case Else
            Debug.Print "Some shady stuff is going on!"
    End Select    
End Sub
```

Thanks for the tip again!